# invalid reporter '[object Object]' on Gitlab Pipeline Cypress Mochawesome reported

Tags: cypress, gitlab-ci

Running commands works fine in the terminal but right after pushing it shows invalid reporter '[object Object]' on Gitlab Pipeline

Have anyone faced same issues ?

[Error on pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNmiG.png)

Gitlab YML file

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
## Set environment variables for folders in "cache" job settings for npm modules and Cypress binary
variables:
  npm_config_cache: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm'
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress'
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - .cache/*
    - cache/Cypress
    - node_modules
    - build
## Install NPM dependencies and Cypress
install:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome106-ff106
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
test-file:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome106-ff106
  stage: test
  script:
    # start the server in the background
    - npm start &
    # run Cypress tests in parallel
    - npx cypress run --reporter-options reportDir="cypress/results",overwrite=false,html=false,json=true
    - npx mochawesome-merge "cypress/results/*.json" > mochawesome.json
    - npx marge mochawesome.json
```

cypress.config.js file

```
reporter: 'mochawesome',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'cypress/results',
    overwrite: false,
    html: false,
    json: true,
  },
```

Error in Gitlab pipeline

```
invalid reporter '[object Object]'
TypeError: invalid reporter '[object Object]'
    at createInvalidReporterError (<embedded>:2965:139888)
    at k.reporter (<embedded>:2970:3431)
    at new k (<embedded>:2970:1480)
    at S.setRunnables (<embedded>:4515:15044)
    at Object.onTestsReceivedAndMaybeRecord (<embedded>:4562:27485)
    at p.<anonymous> (<embedded>:4515:45115)
    at p.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at <embedded>:4515:24385
'[object Object]' reporter not found
```